# How do I upgrade to latest versions in VS 2017 Vue template?

Tags: typescript, webpack, asp.net-core, vuejs2

I have been having nothing but problems trying to upgrade my project to the latest version of Vue and other projects. I created the project using `dotnet new vue`. This created a project that works but uses old versions of packages.

I am trying to update all my packages to the latest versions, but I seem to be getting this error when I run my project:

`[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.`

I was able to reproduce this with a standard Asp.Net Vue project and this package.json file (no other modifications)...

```
{
    "name": "vuetest",
    "private": true,
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.0",
        "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.4.0",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
        "event-source-polyfill": "^0.0.12",
        "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
        "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
        "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
        "jquery": "^3.1.1",
        "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
        "typescript": "^2.6.1",
        "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
        "vue": "^2.5.8",
        "vue-loader": "^13.5.0",
        "vue-property-decorator": "^6.0.0",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.8",
        "webpack": "^3.8.1",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.20.0"
    }
}
```

I have tried a bunch of different things, but almost all of the technologies in the project are new to me (Vue, webpack, TypeScript, NPM, ASP.Net Core), so I have no idea which layer is broken. I've seen other pages that talk about this error, but the solutions either don't seem to apply to this particular stack or just didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure how asp.net factors in your application? Do you write a server-side vue app in C#? If ALL these techniques are new to you, you might want to start a bit simpler, for example by just building the typescript+webpack project from microsoft's vue-starter repository. That should work out of the box and give you an idea of how all these techniques work.

Comment: @Kokodoko Thanks for the suggestion, I hadn't seen that repo before, I might do that if I can't get this to work pretty soon though I'm really hoping to build it using ASP.Net MVC (it's just the "core" part that I'm not familiar with, the rest of MVC I've got many years of experience with). However, perhaps if I start with something more basic, I can figure out how to introduce the rest later.

Comment: You might consider using asp.net to generate JSON data and render that with a client side Vue app.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with separate projects for my API and SPA. I used the Quasar CLI to create the SPA project, but I'm sure I would have done fine using the Vue CLI as well.

The folder structure has the API and SPA as siblings. In the API, I made sure all my routes start with "\api" and I've added middleware for static files that points to the compiled output of the SPA (this is a configuration setting so I can deploy both however I want). For development purposes, I use the hot reloading feature built into whatever the Quasar CLI used for this feature and setup the server to proxy the "\api" calls to the API project, which I leave running in IIS Express. I use the "Start Without Debugging" command, this allows me to make changes to the API and recompile and it continues to work.

This seems to be working very well for me and allows me to make changes and see those changes immediately without having to run through a bunch of build and deploy steps.